# Catching animation recyclerview items

Tags: android

I want animate items on RecyclerView like this [EXAMPLE](https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/bcd1d317689189.562bd9932b830.gif). How  can I do it? I tried to use the library [Rebound](http://facebook.github.io/rebound/) but it does not give me the desired result. Please help me.

Comment: Can you please present something? What kind of result did you get?

Comment: Maybe this article will help you https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-complex-lists-with-the-android-recyclerview/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.